# how do i call my game over method when the health is equal to 0?

Tags: if-statement, methods, global-variables, health-monitoring, method-call

I am making a game for my computers class in `Java`, I am using `NetBeans`. It is more like a choose your own adventure game. This is my health method that I call if they choose an option that will cause damage to them.

It works fine, it takes the damage off the way I want it to. The one problem I am having is putting an if statement that sends it to the gameover method.
It is giving me the below error -

```
incompatible types
Required: boolean
Found: int
```

Please help me fix this.

```
package sauvelostdog;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SauveLostDog {

   //set starting health to 10

  static int playerHealth = 10;

    public static void health(int damageAmount) {

       int damage;

       //player taking 3 damage
        if (damageAmount == 3) {
            damage = 3;
            playerHealth = playerHealth - damage;
            System.out.println(playerHealth);
        } else if (damageAmount == 4) {
            //player taking 4 damage
            damage = 4;
            playerHealth = playerHealth - damage;
            System.out.println(playerHealth);
        } else if (damageAmount == 5) {
            //player taking 5 damage
            damage = 5;
            playerHealth = playerHealth - damage;
            System.out.println(playerHealth);
        }
            //this is what is giving me problems
            if(playerHealth => 0){
            gameover();

     }
 }
```

Comment: By the way, there is a `}` missing for the second `if` statement.

Comment: `=>` ?? check operators. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Variable playerhealth would have to be equal to or less than zero.  You are essentially outputting `gameover();` when you have health greater than or equal to zero.

```
if(playerHealth <= 0){
    gameover();
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but `=>` is not the same as `>=`. He is not outputting `gameover();` when he has heath greater than or equal to zero, he is getting an error because it expects a boolean, but instead he is assigning `playerHealth` the value 0, so it gets an int. (I think that is what is happening, not 100% sure what `=>` does in java)